# How to use random.randit in a function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
units['pm']={'as': 2, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10}
```

Then I have a simple group of 'if statements':

```
p1attackers = 50
p2attackers = 50
p1att= 0

if units['pm']['de'] == 2:

import random

for i in xrange(p1attackers):
    key = random.randint(1,10)  
    if key == 1:
        p1att += 1
    elif key == 2:
        p1att += 1
    else:
        p1att += 0
```

Basically what is occurring here is, the 'random.randit' chooses 50 numbers and if those numbers are 1 or 2, a 1 is added to p1att. Is there anyway to make this whole thing smaller or shorter. Perhaps without the use of 'if statements' and in a function?

Comment: You'll need to provide fixes for your indentation and fix the code to be working (there is an `if` missing somewhere).

Comment: There's no `randit` function. Perhaps you meant `randint`?

Comment: Also, the `else` condition is superfluous, no matter which is the correct indentation.

Answer (score 3):

you can actually just do:

`sum((random.randint(1,5) == 1) for i in xrange(50))`

also, with numpy, i think you could do something like:

`np.random.binomial(50, .2)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension:

```
p1att = sum([1 for _ in xrange(p1attackers) if (random.randint(1, 10) <= 2)])
```

Edit:
or as suggested by Adam Cushner, you can not use them:

```
p1att = sum(1 for _ in xrange(p1attackers) if (random.randint(1, 10) <= 2))
```

Comment: there's no reason to first create a list from a list comprehension and then sum up that resulting list (in other words, to fix it, remove the brackets)

Comment: yeah, it's kinda cool. sum's just going to iterate over whatever iterable you pass it, so you might as well pass it a generator expression and save some time/space.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in xrange(p1attackers):
    key = random.randint(1,10)  
    if key == 1:
        p1att += 1
    elif key == 2:
        p1att += 1
```

means `add 1 to p1att 50 times on a probability of 2/10`

you can simplify it in

```
p1att = sum(1 for _ in xrange(p1attackers) if random.randint(1,10) < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the for block can be replaced by:

`p1att += 1 if (random.randint(1, 10) <= 2) else 0`

which is Python's **conditional assignment**.

Comment: A little explaination wouldn't harm

Answer (score 0):

Some parentheses added for readability:

```
from random import randint
p1attackers = 100 # for example

p1att = sum(1 if (randint(1,10) <= 2) else 0 for _ in range(p1attackers))
```

or

```
p1att = sum(1 for _ in range(p1attackers) if randint(1,10) <= 2)
```

or

```
p1att = sum((randint(1,10) <= 2) for _ in range(p1attackers))
```

Isn't python beautiful?